# Improve performance by using Linq methods

Tags: c#, angular, linq, asynchronous

I have used the following code to retrieve the content of a JSON feed and as you see I have used the paging techniques and Skip and Take methods like this. My paging works fine, however I can't see any performance improvement and I know this is because every time I request a new page it calls the API again and again and after retrieving all contents, it filters it using `Skip` and `Take` methods, **I am looking for a way to apply the `Skip` and `Take` methods with my `HttpClient` so that it only retrieves the needed records for every page.** Is it possible? If so, how??:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<myPaginatedReturnedData> MyMethod(int page)
{
    int perPage = 10;
    int start = (page - 1) * perPage;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("externalAPI");
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType =
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        IEnumerable<myReturnedData> data = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<myReturnedData>>(content);
        myPaginatedReturnedData datasent = new myPaginatedReturnedData
        {
            Count = data.Count(),
            myReturnedData = data.Skip(start).Take(perPage).ToList(),
        };
        return datasent;
    }
}
```

If there isn't anyway to do this, I can retrieve the full collection from the external api and moving it to my front-end (Anguar) to page it there, by using this way the data is transferred just once and then paged at the client side that seems to be very better than making the external API to return a full set of data to my server **every time the client changes the page**. Is this correct and server side paging useless for me in this case?

Comment: If the external api you call doesn't support paging in an **explicit** way (e.g. with additional query string arguments), then you are out of luck.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So you mean that isn't there anyway to only request and retrieve the needed records from that API? So should I prefer to use front-end angular paging without server side paging and work with the full collection in memory which seems to be slow just first time and then it will be more faster.

Comment: Retrieving the full collection from the external api and moving it to anguar to page it there sounds like the data is transferred just once and then paged at the client side. Otherwise, you make the external api return a full set of data to your server everytime the client changes the page.

Comment: @WiktorZychla So, do you agree that client side paging is more better in this case? Should I go with client-side paging only, since I haven't any control on external API?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like your only option here.

Comment: FYI: You should pretty much always use a singleton HttpClient, since it doesn't scale well at all if not reused. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Posting the same question multiple times is not a good idea on this site.